# Is this the correct approach of using Realm in Android?

Tags: java, android, realm

I've decided to use Realm to one of my Android app. That's why I'm just trying to make a simple app with Realm for R&D purpose. But I'm confused if it is the correct way to use Realm. My project is working and showing data correctly. Here are my codes-

I created a java class `RealmDB.java`:

```
package com.github.abdalimran.realmandroid;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

public class RealmDB extends Application{

    private Realm myRealm;

    public RealmDB(Context context) {
        myRealm = Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("myOtherRealm.realm")
                .build());
    }

    public void addData(PersonDetailsModel p) {
        myRealm.beginTransaction();
        PersonDetailsModel person = myRealm.createObject(PersonDetailsModel.class);
        person.setName(p.getName());
        person.setAge(p.getAge());
        person.setEmail(p.getEmail());
        person.setAddress(p.getAddress());
        myRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

    public RealmResults getAllData() {
        RealmResults<PersonDetailsModel> query = myRealm.where(PersonDetailsModel.class).findAll();
        return query;
    }

    public void closeRealm() {
        myRealm.close();
    }
}
```

Now I am creating an instance of this class and perform operations using the methods.

Here is my Realm Object class `PersonDetailsModel.java`:

```
package com.github.abdalimran.realmandroid;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class PersonDetailsModel extends RealmObject
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "ID: "+getId()+"\n"+
                "Name: "+getName()+"\n"+
                "Age: "+getAge()+"\n"+
                "Email: "+getEmail()+"\n"+
                "Address: "+getAddress()+"\n";
    }
}
```

This is the `MainActivity.java` where I'm instantiating the RealmDB class and performing operations:

```
package com.github.abdalimran.realmandroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvPersonNameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvPersonNameList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPersonNameList);

        RealmDB rdb=new RealmDB(this);

        Log.i("list",""+rdb.getAllData());

        if(rdb.getAllData()==null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No data found. Add person.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            ArrayAdapter<PersonDetailsModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    rdb.getAllData());
            lvPersonNameList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    public void AddPerson(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AddPersonActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is my `AddPersonActivity.java` class-

```
package com.github.abdalimran.realmandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class AddPersonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name;
    private EditText age;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText address;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_person);

        name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        address= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    }

    public void AddPerson(View view) {

        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddhhmmssMs");
        String uniqueid = ft.format(dNow);

        Log.i("uniqueid",uniqueid);

        String sname=name.getText().toString();
        String sage=age.getText().toString();
        String semail=email.getText().toString();
        String saddress=address.getText().toString();

        PersonDetailsModel person=new PersonDetailsModel();
        person.setId(uniqueid);
        person.setName(sname);
        person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(sage));
        person.setEmail(semail);
        person.setAddress(saddress);

        RealmDB rdb=new RealmDB(getApplicationContext());
        rdb.addData(person);
        rdb.closeRealm();
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach to implement Realm into Android project?

Mostly I'm confused with the following code:

```
public void addData(PersonDetailsModel p) {
        myRealm.beginTransaction();
        PersonDetailsModel person = myRealm.createObject(PersonDetailsModel.class);
        person.setName(p.getName());
        person.setAge(p.getAge());
        person.setEmail(p.getEmail());
        person.setAddress(p.getAddress());
        myRealm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

Here I have a parameter `PersonDetailsModel p`. But I'm creating a realm object using `myRealm.createObject(PersonDetailsModel.class);` and then getting the data from `p` and setting it to `person`. Isn't there a way to directly set the parameter `p` into `createObject()`?

Comment: Are you just looking for a yes/no? What is the problem?  Does it work? Or are you wanting someone to review it and potentially refactor the code?

Comment: Personally, I think you should store `rdb.getAllData()` into a variable so you don't continuously query the database, but nothing looks wrong with what you have

Comment: Yes..this is working. But I'm not sure If I am implementing it the right way. I want someone to review my approach and suggest If I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If it works then why do you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class RealmDB extends Application {
    public RealmDB(Context context) {
```

Based on these two lines, I can tell you quite clearly that it isn't.

And with that,

0.a) you shouldn't make "Application" instances by hand, "Application" is created by Android

0.b) Your `public RealmResults getAllData() {` should be `public RealmResults<PersonDetailsModel> getAllData() {`

1.) you are not using `RealmBaseAdapter` and you should, because currently you don't handle updates in the Realm either with `RealmBaseAdapter` nor with `RealmChangeListener`

2.) you are not using `executeTransactionAsync()` on the UI thread and you should (in fact, you should use `executeTransaction()` for synchronous transactions, and you shouldn't execute synchronous writes on the UI thread)

3.) your Realm instance created in MainActivity is never closed

4.) you should retain a field variable to your `RealmResults` to prevent it from getting GC'd (although `ArrayAdapter` might also latch onto it, so you won't run into the problem that comes from *not* retaining a field variable to the results)

Comment: WoW..great..thanks for your valuable suggestion. I've added one more point of confusion in this post. Would please check that out?

Comment: I have a parameter PersonDetailsModel p. But I'm creating a realm object using myRealm.createObject(PersonDetailsModel.class); and then getting the data from p and setting it to person. Isn't there a way to directly set the parameter p into createObject()?

Comment: No, but you should specify the `createObject(PersonDetailsModel.class, primaryKey)` if you use this method. I tend to use `insertOrUpdate()` though using 1 detached copy for all inserted realm objects

Comment: By the way, my profile has an article which links to a very simple sample project, demonstrating usage of Realm :p